# How to reset the value of antd autocomplete, if the value is not in the data source

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, antd

I'm using ant design `AutoComplete` for a location selection. And the data source is an array. Here is my code.

```
<Form.Item
   label={t("City")}
   name="location"
   rules={[
      {
          required: true,
          message: t("Please enter your city"),
      },
   ]}
   >
       <AutoComplete
          options={this.props.cityList}
          allowClear={true}
          placeholder={t("Enter your city")}
          className="ant-select-custom"
          filterOption={(inputValue, option) =>
             option.value.toUpperCase().indexOf(inputValue.toUpperCase()) !== -1
          }
       />
</Form.Item>
```

The problem is, I can type anything that not in the data source. What I want it to restrict that. If I type something that not in the data source, The value should be erased. I tried with `onBlur()` and `onChange()` but no luck. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set value props in AutoComplete tag, and set an state for it, check if value on search is not found change the state to the initial.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState('');

const handleSearch = async val => {
    if (val) {
      const response = await dispatch(yourAction(val));
      if (!response?.length) {
        ...
        setValue(''); // this will clear the input
      } else {
        ...
      }
    } else {
      ...
    }
};

<AutoComplete
 ...,
 value={value}
/>
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting an alternative answer because I was led here with a very similar problem and the provided answer doesn't quite do what I needed.

Autocomplete doesn't natively clear the input if the searched text is not found on the `options` `values` and therefore does not trigger the `required: true` validation if the user enters random data. The `Select` component on the other hand won't let the user add anything that is not provided on the `options` array. If you use the `showSearch` attribute it will filter what the user typed and perform a case insensitive match with the `value` from `options` Array. This means that in the case below, if the user types `new` he will only be presented with `New York` option and unless he clicks the option, the input will **not** be "dirty" and will display `City is required` if the user blurs the input.

```
  const cities = ["New York", "Chicago", "Miami"]

  <Form.Item 
    name="city"
    label="City"
    rules={[{ required: true, message: "City is required" }]}
>
      <Select
       options={cities.map((city) => ({ label: city, value: city }))}
       placeholder="New York"
       showSearch
       />
   </Form.Item>
```